# Weighted least squares formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, least-squares, matrix-analysis, weighted-least-squares

I was studying the weighted least squares algorithm and came across this formula for calculating the weighted result in terms of the original.

Here $x_{LS}$ is the solution for $D=I$
[image: Goloub, G. & Van Loan, C. Matrix computations pp. 265]

I can't figure out the proof for this formula. I see that $x_D=(A^TD^2A)^{-1}A^TD^2b$ but haven't been able to derive the formula from the book. Does anyone know a demonstration?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u=\arg\min_x\|Ax-b\|^2,\qquad v=\arg\min_x\|DAx-Db\|^2.$$

It [follows that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433271/theorem-1-1-of-the-mathematics-of-computerized-tomography/4433864#4433864) $$A^*(Au-b)=0,\qquad (DA)^*(DAv-Db)=0.$$

Therefore, $$\begin{eqnarray*}(A^*D^2A)^{-1}A^*(D^2-I)(b-Au)&=&(A^*D^2A)^{-1}(A^*D^2(b-Au)-A^*(b-Au))\\&=&(A^*D^2A)^{-1}(A^*D^2(b-Au))\\&=&
(A^*D^2A)^{-1}(A^*D^2b-A^*D^2Au)\\&=&(A^*D^2A)^{-1}(DA)^*(Db)-u\\&=&(A^*D^2A)^{-1}(DA)^*(DAv+(Db-DAv))-u\\&=&v-u.\end{eqnarray*}$$

You may find interesting discussions about related results such as [Why are the four fundamental subspaces fundamental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783390/why-are-the-four-fundamental-subspaces-fundamental%3F#answer-1784064),  searching for "[\(A^*(Au-b)=0\)](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28A%5E%2a%28Au-b%29%3D0%5C%29%20)" on SearchOnMath.